# MAC variant of MSR DUKPT?

Tags: encryption, emv, credit-card-track-data, dukpt

Currently I am working on a ChipCard EMV device decryption. Down below is the related data I have after using the transaction (TLV format as Tag Length Value):

```
<DFDF54> --- It means KSN
0A
950003000005282005B4 


<DFDF59>---- per instruction, it is called Encrypted Data Primative
82      ---- length of value in hex, when more than 255 degits, use 82
00D815F35E7846BF4F34E56D7A42E9D24A59CDDF8C3D565CD3D42A341D4AD84B0B7DBFC02DE72A57770D4F795FAB2CE3A1F253F22E0A8BA8E36FA3EA38EE8C95FEBA3767CDE0D3FBB6741A47BE6734046B8CBFB6044C6EE5F98C9DABCD47BC3FD371F777E7E1DCFA16EE5718FKLIOE51A749C7ECC736CB7780AC39DE062DAACC318219E9AAA26E3C2CE28B82C8D22178DA9CCAE6BBA20AC79AB985FF13611FE80E26C34D27E674C63CAC1933E3F9B1BE319A5D12D16561C334F931A5E619243AF398D9636B0A8DC2ED5C6D1C7C795C00D083C08953BC8679C60
```

I know BDK for this device is `0123456789ABCDEFFEDCBA9876543210`. Per decryption instruction, it mentioned that DFDF59 contains the following tags:

```
FC<len>/* container for encrypted generic data */
    F2<len>/*container for Batch Data*/
           ... /*Batch Data tags*/
    F3<len>/*container for Reversal Data, if any*/
           ... /*Reversal Data tags*/
```

Per instruction, it mentioned "**MAC variant of MSR DUKPT**", where MAC stands for message authentication code, and "**Parse the data through TLV format. For encrypted data tag, use TDES_Decrypt_CBC to decrypt it**".

I tried to use 3DES DUKPT using KSN, BDK, and encrypted data DFDF59. It wouldn't work. Can anyone in decryption field give me some advice? Our vendor is very reluctant to share their knowledge ...

I have no idea how MAC is really playing a role here in decryption.... I thought MAC is just an integrity check.... I am using session key for 3DES DUKPT that was generated from KSN and BDK. this works for other decryptions in this device, but doesn't solve the DFDF59 (chip card EMV decryption).... That is why I start to wonder whether I am using the right session key or not.... Feel free to just throw ideas out there. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at DUKPT internals it generates a transaction key out of the current future keys and encryption counter. This 'transaction key' for a specific KSN has several variants (which effectively are just xor masks that you put on the transaction key to differentiate it for PIN, MAC req, MAC rsp, data encryption req and rsp usages). These variants mean that you use a different key to generate PIN and different key to encrypt data (so that you cannot ie. decrypt/attack PINblock when able to select data buffer arbitrarily). Using MAC variant means only that for the encryption operation you will be using a certain mask for the DUKPT transaction key.